# How to use emacs alphabet key bind even with Thai input method

Tags: emacs

I'm emacs user and learning Thai language.

I can read and write Thai characters with Emacs comfortably.
But all Emacs key binding can't be used with Thai input mode.

For example when I try to use `C-g`, the result is `C-เ is undefined`.
The reason I can not use `C-g` is quite clear, but I don't know how to circumvent the issue.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

### OS

OS X version 10.9.5

Comment: 1. What `emacs` version do you use? 2. Do you use `set-input-method` to select input method? 3. Did you try with `emacs -q`? 4. On `emacs 24.5.1` I am still able to use `C-` and `M-` keybindings after selecting both `thai-kesmanee` and `thai-pattachote` input method with `set-input-method`.

Comment: I didn't know I can change input method inside emacs, thank. With `set-input-method` the keybinding still active. But I rather to use OS IME because I want to change input method whatever application I'm using. I add OS info to my question.